# File not fetching for unzipping while executing for the first time

Tags: java, file, unzip

I am trying unzip a file but when I am executing it for the first time it is getting failed although the file is getting downloaded and is in directory. Executing it for the second time it is working fine.

```java
public class UnzipLatestZipFile {

    private String unzippedFileName; 

    public void processLatestZipFile() {
        String downloadsFolderPath = System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "Downloads";
        String unzippedFolderPath = downloadsFolderPath + File.separator + "unzipped";
        File latestZipFile = getLatestZipFile(downloadsFolderPath);

        if (latestZipFile != null) {
            System.out.println("Latest Zip File: " + latestZipFile.getName());
            try {
                unzipFile(latestZipFile, unzippedFolderPath);
                System.out.println("File successfully unzipped to: " + unzippedFolderPath);
                System.out.println("Unzipped File Name: " + unzippedFileName);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Error unzipping file: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("No zip files found in the Downloads folder.");
        }
    }
    private File getLatestZipFile(String folderPath) {
        File downloadsFolder = new File(folderPath);

        File[] files = downloadsFolder.listFiles((dir, name) -> name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".zip"));

        if (files != null && files.length > 0) {
            Arrays.sort(files, Comparator.comparingLong(File::lastModified).reversed());
            return files[0];
        }

        return null; 
    }

    private void unzipFile(File zipFile, String outputFolder) throws IOException {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        try (ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(zipFile))) {
            File outputDir = new File(outputFolder);
            if (!outputDir.exists()) {
                outputDir.mkdirs();
            }
            ZipEntry zipEntry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry();
            while (zipEntry != null) {
                String entryName = zipEntry.getName();
                File entryFile = new File(outputFolder + File.separator + entryName);
                new File(entryFile.getParent()).mkdirs();

                if (!zipEntry.isDirectory()) {
                    try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(entryFile)) {
                        int len;
                        while ((len = zipInputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                            fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
                        }
                    }
                    unzippedFileName = entryFile.getName();
                }

                zipEntry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am expecting it to get executed every time, not that I have to rerun it.

Comment: Sooo, stupid question - has the file finished downloaded (and been flushed/streams closed) before you try unzipping it?

Comment: Your code works fine for me, I would consider making use of [`File(String, String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) and [`File(File, String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.io.File,java.lang.String)) over concatenating your strings paths, but that's not a massive issue - again, I think you'll find that the file isn't fully realised when you try opening it, but that's guess work